# How to color background with padding?

Tags: html, css

I found the following timeline example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/darcyvoutt/pen/ogPrpK), and I try to give a single block a background color (e.g. red). Unfortunately, colouring an entire block works only as you see on the screenshot below, since `.timeline` introduces a padding of 50px. Is there any chance to cover the entire block including the padding?

```
@spacing: 50px;

.timeline {
  [...]
  padding: @spacing;  
}
```

[image]

Comment: With the way the current padding is applied to the timeline element and child `<li>` elements it doesn't look like it's possible. However, it should be possible if you emulate the padding you have applied on the timeline element via the child `<li>`'s. Are you able to do this? i.e. would this be an option you could use

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I could accept that as an answer